# Is it possible to override the classpath declared in Runner.path() with the command-line?

Tags: karate

I'm having a karate test project where my folder structure would be like below, I have organized the folder (hunting-skills) based on the type. I have configured cucumber reporting and parallel execution with 1 thread, below is the code for parallel execution and cucumber reporting

```
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
public class FeatureTests {
    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:hunting-skills").tags("~@ignore").parallel(1);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
        ArrayList<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "someTests");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

```
src/test/java
|
+--karate-config.js
+--FeatureTests.java
|
\-- hunting-skills
    \-- animals
    |
    +-- lionTest.feature
    +-- tigerTest.feature
    |
    \-- birds
    |
    +-- valtureTest.feature
    +-- eagleTest.feature
    |
```

The complete suite ran when the following command `./gradlew test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=FeatureTests` is run in terminal (say git bash or Linux terminal) which is expected.

But at times I want to run a specific folder or *.feature file. I have got commands from the karate GitHub page https://github.com/intuit/karate

```
(to run specific folder) ./gradlew test "-Dkarate.options=--tags ~@ignore classpath:hunting-skills/animals Dtest=FeatureTests
(to run specific file) ./gradlew test "-Dkarate.options=--tags ~@ignore classpath:hunting-skills/animals/lionTest.feature Dtest=FeatureTests
```

When I run the command for a specific file, the complete suite ran. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Write another test entry point that does not set the `path()` or read system properties manually and use Java code and if-then conditions. Don't waste your time trying to "re use".